# Using a HelpId in an HtmlHelp call

Tags: c++, winapi, chm

I have a function call in C++:

```
HtmlHelp(NULL, pszFile, HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, helpId)
```

My `helpId` is a `CString`. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/about-the-html-help-viewer), the function's `helpId` is a `DWORD_PTR` instead.

What can I do to call some `.chm` help file with a specific ID (number or string)?

Comment: Just cast the CString object.  Hopefully (wchar_t*), might be (char*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `dwData` parameter depends on the value of the `uCommand` parameter.

In the case of `uCommand=HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC`, the `dwData` parameter is expected to hold a `TCHAR*` pointer to a null-terminated C-style string.  Refer to the `CString` documentation for how to [use CString as a C-Style Null-Terminated String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/cstring-operations-relating-to-c-style-strings?view=vs-2017#_core_using_cstring_as_a_c.2d.style_null.2d.terminated_string).

For example:

```
CString helpId = ...;
HtmlHelp(NULL, pszFile, HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, (DWORD_PTR) (LPCTSTR) helpId);
```

Or:

```
CString helpId = ...;
HtmlHelp(NULL, pszFile, HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, (DWORD_PTR) helpId.GetString());
```